# Why the return executes before the item is created and the console.log awaits and shows the correct id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, promise, async-await

I'm using node.js, express, and pnp (sharepoint) to insert a list item, the problem is that the id returned to console.log is correct but when i try to send back the id created it goes empty. how come thhe console.log awaits for the code and the return doesnt?

here is my code:

```
app.use(express.json());

//Método inserir emergencia
app.post('/inserirEmergencia', function(req, res){
    var retorno = inserirEmergencia(req);
    return res.json(retorno);
});

app.listen(3001);

async function inserirEmergencia(req) {

var retornoItemAdd;

const listAdd = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Emergências").items.add({
        Descricao: req.body.Descricao,
        NomeId: req.body.NomeId,
        DataEmergencia: req.body.DataEmergencia,
        TipoEmergenciaId: req.body.TipoEmergenciaId,
        SubtipoEmergenciaId: req.body.SubtipoEmergenciaId,
        Email: req.body.Email,
        Telefone: req.body.Telefone,
        LocalSetorEndereco: req.body.LocalSetorEndereco,
        Estado: req.body.Estado,
        Municipio: req.body.Municipio
    }).then((iar) => {
            console.log(iar); //waits for the creation
            return iar; //executes without waiting

    }).catch((err) => {
            retornoItemAdd = err;
            console.log(err);
            return err;
        });
  }
```

I update the code to:

so, thanks for the reply, i edited and removed the then..but still the same thing happens..

```
async function inserirEmergencia(req) {

    const listAdd = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Emergências").items.add({
        Descricao: req.body.Descricao,
        NomeId: req.body.NomeId,
        DataEmergencia: req.body.DataEmergencia,
        TipoEmergenciaId: req.body.TipoEmergenciaId,
        SubtipoEmergenciaId: req.body.SubtipoEmergenciaId,
        Email: req.body.Email,
        Telefone: req.body.Telefone,
        LocalSetorEndereco: req.body.LocalSetorEndereco,
        Estado: req.body.Estado,
        Municipio: req.body.Municipio
    });

    console.log(listAdd);
    return listAdd;

}
```

Comment: Don't mix `await` with `.then`.

Comment: As you're using await, the function `then` it's unnecessary,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like that:

```
//Método inserir emergencia
app.post('/inserirEmergencia', function(req, res){
  let retorno = inserirEmergencia(req).then(
    iar => {
      console.log(iar);
      res.json(iar);
    }
  );  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the call of function `then` and modify your approach and leave only `await` operators.

```
app.use(express.json());

//Método inserir emergencia
app.post('/inserirEmergencia', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    var retorno = await inserirEmergencia(req);
    return res.json(retorno);
  } catch (e) {
    //Error handling
  }
});

app.listen(3001);

async function inserirEmergencia(req) {
  const listAdd = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Emergências").items.add({
    Descricao: req.body.Descricao,
    NomeId: req.body.NomeId,
    DataEmergencia: req.body.DataEmergencia,
    TipoEmergenciaId: req.body.TipoEmergenciaId,
    SubtipoEmergenciaId: req.body.SubtipoEmergenciaId,
    Email: req.body.Email,
    Telefone: req.body.Telefone,
    LocalSetorEndereco: req.body.LocalSetorEndereco,
    Estado: req.body.Estado,
    Municipio: req.body.Municipio
  });

  return listAdd;
}
```

Comment: I did this and the behavior continues...maybe now is something with the json

Comment: great!, yw `(:`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the code works.

it goes like this..

```
//Método inserir emergencia
app.post('/inserirEmergencia', function(req, res){
    let retorno = inserirEmergencia(req).then(
      iar => {
        console.log(iar);
        res.json(iar);
      }
    );  
  });

app.listen(3001);

async function inserirEmergencia(req) {

    const listAdd = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Emergências").items.add({
        Descricao: req.body.Descricao,
        NomeId: req.body.NomeId,
        DataEmergencia: req.body.DataEmergencia,
        TipoEmergenciaId: req.body.TipoEmergenciaId,
        SubtipoEmergenciaId: req.body.SubtipoEmergenciaId,
        Email: req.body.Email,
        Telefone: req.body.Telefone,
        LocalSetorEndereco: req.body.LocalSetorEndereco,
        Estado: req.body.Estado,
        Municipio: req.body.Municipio
    });

    console.log(listAdd);
    return listAdd;

}
```